# about reverse url for category get_absolute_url

Tags: django, django-urls

## this is my Category get_absolute_url

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('products:categories_display', args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

## This is my product view

```
class category_slug_view(ObjectViewedMixin, DetailView):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    template_name = "products/product_page.html"
```

## This is my product url

```
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', category_slug_view.as_view()),
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to ask here!

Answer (score 1):

To use reverse `products:categories_display` you need to:

1. Make sure you have `app_name = 'products'` in your app's `urls.py`.
2. Name your url pattern

```
app_name = 'products'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', category_slug_view.as_view(), name='categories_display'),
]
```

As an aside, the recommendation in Python/Django is to name your class-based-view `CategorySlugView` to make it clear that it is a class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your `url(..)` a *name*, and perhaps a namespace as well:

```
app_name = 'products'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', category_slug_view.as_view(), name='categories_display'),
]
```

Since [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0), you can make use of `path(..)`s, which is usually more compact and readable:

```
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'products'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', category_slug_view.as_view(), name='categories_display'),
]
```

It might be better to use named arguments in your `reverse(..)` function call:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse(
        'products:categories_display',
        kwargs={'id': self.id, 'slug': self.slug}
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my get_absolute_url to this

def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('categories_display', args=[self.id, self.slug])

And i gave my url pattern a name

```
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', category_slug_view.as_view(), name='categories_display'),
```